# display data attribute element of the current slider

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in JS, I made a carousel with a data attribute and I want to display it and it have to change when we go the next or previous slider.

For the moment I made a small script and I can display only the data attribute of the first slider

HTML :

```
<div class="carousel2partsUp slick-initialized slick-slider">
  <div class="el-carousel2parts slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-legend="legend1">
{#    Content #}
</div>
  <div class="el-carousel2parts slick-slide" data-legend="legend2">{#    Content #}</div>
  <div class="el-carousel2parts slick-slide" data-legend="legend3">{#    Content #}</div>
  <div class="el-carousel2parts slick-slide" data-legend="legend4">{#    Content #}</div>
</div>
<span id="legend"></span>
```

JS :

```
<script>
  var carousel = document.querySelector('.el-carousel2parts');
  var spanLegend = document.querySelector('#legend');
  var dataLegend = carousel.dataset.legend;
  spanLegend.innerHTML = dataLegend;
</script>
```

How can I improve my code to display the data attribute according to the good slider ?

should I make a loop ? or something with a event click ?

Thanks for answer

Comment: Just a quick question: slick already provides the possibility to add a legend for each slide, might even be with an attribute on the element itself. Why not use this? This would probably also reduce the additional css needed to get your solution working.

Comment: Add the moment you only select the first `.el-carousel2parts` element. Try using [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Or use the in-built functionality, if the used library has it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one active slide you can do it without loop:

```
  var carousel = document.querySelector('.el-carousel2parts');
  var spanLegend = document.querySelector('#legend');

  // Find which is active and get its attribute:
  var currentSlide = document.querySelector('.slick-active');
  var currentData = currentSlide.getAttribute('data-legend');

  var dataLegend = currentData;
  spanLegend.innerHTML = dataLegend;
```

I do not see you full code, so just a guess.You can make onClick function and call new two lines of code. Put onClick on button which updates the slides. Imagine we have several buttons that scroll through the slides.

```
<button class="turn">Left</button>
<button class="turn">Right</button>
```

In that case we can have something like this:

```
  var spanLegend = document.querySelector('#legend');
  var btnsTurn = document.querySelectorAll('.turn'); 
  btnsTurn.forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener("click", () => {
          var currentSlide = document.querySelector('.slick-active');
          var currentData = currentSlide.getAttribute('data-legend');
          spanLegend.innerHTML = currentData;
      });
  })
```

But I assume that you already have a function which add Class 'slick-active' and remove it from another slide. So you can just add some code inside it without new forEach for the same buttons.

PS You take an Attribute from your DOM which can be edited by any user. In general, be careful innerHTML is a dangerous function.

Hope this helps! Regards,

Comment: That's what I wanted thanks, your answer inspired me, I was able to adapt it to my code